# Cryptography.Hazmat AES Cipher Output Length

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, string-length

In Python, using the `Cryptography.Hazmat` module For AES, the output length of the encryption is not the a multiple of 16; am I implementing the encryption cipher wrong, and if so, what is wrong? The output length I recieve is `16 + len(input)` (16 as it is the length of the IV). Here is the code below:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.algorithms import AES
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.modes import CBC,OFB,CFB

class AES_Cipher:   
  def __init__(self,key):
    self.key = key

  def encrypt(self,plain_text):
    initialization_vector = urandom(16)
    cipher = Cipher(AES(self.key),OFB(initialization_vector),backend)
    encryption_engine = cipher.encryptor()
    return initialization_vector + encryption_engine.update(plain_text.encode("utf-8")) + encryption_engine.finalize()

  def decrypt(self,cipher_text):
    initialization_vector = cipher_text[:16]
    cipher = Cipher(AES(self.key),OFB(initialization_vector),backend)
    decryption_engine = cipher.decryptor()
    return (decryption_engine.update(cipher_text[16:]) + decryption_engine.finalize()).decode("utf-8")
```

The cipher is called as so:

```
from hashlib import sha3_256
aes_key = sha3_256(b"Strong Encryption Key").digest()
aes_engine = AES_Cipher(aes_key)
aes_engine.encrypt("Hello World")
```

And this is the result:

`b'\xc4I\xf2\xe5\xf4\xaeX\x96\xa5\xfe\xbd+\xde\x8ca\xd5\xdb\xad\x97S\x01\x81C\x9e\xd5\xd8@'`

This is only 27 bytes long, compared to the expected 32 bytes. The 27 = 16 + len("Hello World"). Why is it not 32 bytes long? What is the code missing? Another thing; decryption works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length of 27 bytes is correct for [OFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Output_Feedback_(OFB))-mode.

The OFB-mode used in the Python-code turns a [block cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher) into a [stream cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher). The difference between block cipher and stream cipher is described in more detail [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/5335). In particular, the length of the plaintext input can be arbitrary for a stream cipher, i.e. in contrast to a block cipher, the length does not have to be an integer multiple of the blocksize, so that *no* [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)) is required. The generated ciphertext has the *same* length as the plaintext.

In the current example, the plaintext *Hello World*, and therefore also the ciphertext, has a length of 11 bytes. Together with the IV, which has a length of 16 bytes, the total length is 27 bytes, which corresponds exactly to your result.